# want to pass the password from the shell script for the scp command for transferring the file from one server to another

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, sh

I am writing a shell script that copys the files from one server to another server using scp command. But each time when I ran the script in command line due to scp command it is asking for password. I don't want to pass the password from command line because their are approx 36 scp commands in the script for transferring the files from so many servers. So I want a suitable way to pass the password from my shell script only. Can someone please help me to pass the password for scp command through the script......thanks...

below is the scp command that I am using in my shell script ----`

```
scp -r root@$source_host:/$source_path root@$destination_host:/$destination_path
```

please can someone help me on this.....Thanks.

Comment: what has this got to do with python?

Comment: You nearly always want to use a public key pair, rather than a password, for automated `ssh` or `scp` connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sshpass for that.

```
sshpass  -p password scp -r root@$source_host:/$source_path root@$destination_host:/$destination_path
```

Comment: thanks... i tried this previously also but while using  sshpass i am getting the following error - 

./test.sh: line 4: sshpass: command not found

I am using CentOS for this.

Comment: @Rishi Arora Run `yum install sshpass` to install it. (i am working with  centos7).